# ¿Por qué ser "hijo, ja de papá" tiene una connotación negativa?

Tags: coloquialismos

"Ser hijo de papá" generalmente se asocia con algo negativo, por ejemplo:

> Pedro Heller: “Que me digan hijo de papá es una de las cosas que más me duele” [[1](http://www.latercera.com/noticia/pedro-heller-no-me-gusta-me-regalen-las-cosas-regalo-genera-vacio/)]

El DLE tiene la siguiente entrada:

> [hijo, ja de papá](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KOGiy39):
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona bien situada, más que por sus propios méritos, por el influjo o el poder de sus padres.

Y una definición más [acá](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/hijo)

> 23. hijo de papá *coloquial, despectivo* El que se aprovecha de la situación económica de sus padres sin buscar medios propios de vida.

También me parece curioso que otra frase muy similar tenga un significado muy distinto: *hijo, ja de padre*. En el DLE se puede encontrar lo siguiente:

> [hijo, ja de padre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KOGiy39#9OhdV0r)
>
> 1. m. y f. coloq. hijo de su padre.

Y para hijo de su padre:

> hijo de su padre.
>
> 1. *m. y f. coloq*. Denota la semejanza del hijo en las inclinaciones, cualidades o figura del padre.

¿Hay alguna razón para que "ser hijo de papá" sea negativo y "ser hijo de padre" no? La frase literal "ser hijo de papá"  no tiene nada de negativo, y pareciera un poco redundante. ¿Cómo se explica el significado despectivo para una frase que parece muy "inocente"?

Comment: Creo que la parte de la definición que dice **más que por sus propios méritos** explica porque es negativo. Ser _importante_ es bueno cuando te lo mereces y malo cuando no.

Comment: @DGaleano creo que Mauricio se refiere a por qué una frase aparentemente inocente ("hijo de papá") llegó a tener un significado despectivo, más que a conocer cuál es la parte despectiva de su significado.

Comment: @DGaleano sí, es exactamente lo que dice Charlie. Una vez lees la definición o has tenido el contexto es claro el significado. Pero para alguien que escucha primera vez no hay alguna "pista" que indique siquiera que se trata de algo negativo. Tampoco ayuda mucho que cambiar la palabra "papá" por "padre" le de un significado completamente distinto a la frase.

Comment: Justo es lo que digo. Ser importante es bueno cuando te lo mereces y malo cuando no. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Hijo de su padre" viene a significar "de tal palo tal astilla" o "la manzana no cae muy lejos del árbol". Como indicas implica *semejanza*, en cualquier aspecto, con un progenitor. "Hijo de papá" tiene el mismo significado que la expresión `nacer con una cuchara de plata en la boca`.

El matiz está en el uso de "papá" frente a "padre" para referirte a tus progenitores. Por lo menos en España uno dice "mi **padre** esto o lo otro", "mi **madre** tal o cual". Solo los niños pequeños usan "papá" o "mamá". Por tanto `niño/hijo de papá` viene a indicar que *papi* está ahí como si fueras un niño pequeño (o que percibes a tu padre de esa manera).

Yo vivo en Estados Unidos y aquí se dice "my dad/my mom" y "your dad/your mom", ya que aquí eso términos tienen distinta connotación. En otros países de habla hispana `papá`, `papi` o `papito` pueden tener distintas connotaciones o significados pero, por lo menos en España, el uso de "papá y mamá" para referirte a tus progenitores cuando hablas con alguien que no es alguno de tus hermanos indica un lazo afectivo *demasiado* estrecho (básicamente, inmaduro e infantil). Yo a mi hermano le puedo decir `A **papá** le ha dado ahora con pintar`, pero al resto del mundo le diría `A mi **padre** le ha dado ahora por pintar` y nunca `A mi **papá/papi** le ha dado ahora por pintar`. Sonaría infantil.

En otras palabras, "hijo de **papá**" viene a significar que "papaíto" (connotación de la palabra como si la usase un niño de cinco años) está ahí para resolverte la mayoría de problemas, empezando por los **económicos**. Un "hijo de papá" no tiene que trabajar duro para conseguir cosas en la vida, porque *papaíto* se ocupa.

De forma parecida, si dijeses que "es hijo/a de su madre", aparte del significado despectivo, podrías implicar semejanza también. Pero si dijeses "niño de *mamá*", tendrías de nuevo la *infantilización* de los usos del término que les da esas connotaciones de "estar protegido", "mimado", "entre algodones", etc.

Comment: Interesante, así que es precisamente el uso de "papá" el que le da esa connotación. Nunca lo habría adivinado porque al menos en Colombia no se presenta la situación que mencionas respecto a "padre" y "papá". La palabra "padre" la veo generalmente cuando hay que rellenar algún formulario o algo que tenga que ver con formalidades. También puede que sea costumbre mía o de mi región, pero no es común oir a alguien en una conversación hablando de sus progenitores en términos de "mis padres". En una conversación, sea con personas cercanas o no, lo normal sería hablar de "mi papá" o "mi mamá".

Comment: @MauricioMartinez Y en España nos llama la atención ese uso :) Aunque ya sabemos que es habitual en muchas partes de Hispanoamérica.

Answer (score 1):

Es interesante la pregunta en cuánto a que, en México, ambas opciones tienen connotación negativa.

**Hijo de papá** también tiene el sentido de alguien que se aprovecha de la situación privilegiada del padre y que además es muy consentido por éste.

Opino que pocas personas te dirían **eres un hijo de tu padre** para denotar similitud con el propio padre; en cambio, usarían una frase indirecta como: *hijo de tigre pintito* o algo similar. ¡Ah! Pero si tú madre te dice: **eres un hijo de tú padre**, si está haciendo alusión a una similitud con tu padre; pero refiriendose a una característica con la que ella no va de acuerdo; por lo tanto, no se puede tomar de manera positiva.

En México, un adulto se puede referir a su padre también como papá en un ámbito más amplio, sin ser considerado infantil. Por lo tanto, hijo de papá podría tender a ser más neutro que hijo de **tu/su padre** o hijo de **papi**.

Pero papi, si está reservado para niños pequeños. Por consiguiente, **hijo de papi** tiene una connotación negativa y se refiere con esta frase a un individuo con un padre que posee una posición económica alta y recibe de éste todo lo que pueda pedir con poca o ninguna restricción.

**Hijo de tu padre** es, más bien, reservado para la madre de uno. Recordemos que en México, **hijo de tu madre** puede llegar a ser un insulto; por esto, la madre usará la palabra padre con el
mismo tono. Sin embargo, es muy dificil que el padre se sienta, realmente, insultado por esta frase.